# Jquery_multiselect error: "undefined method `category_name' for #<Thing:0xa38ac70>"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using this gem: "https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete" to implement a multiselect textbox in my form to create a new Thing. I followed the usage guide exactly, but I'm getting this error when I try to visit `http://localhost:3000/things/new`, the page with my form:

```
NoMethodError in Things#new 
undefined method `category_names' for #<Thing:0xa38ac70>
```

The function of the textbox in question is to associate each new Thing with multiple Categories. Thing and Category each have_many of each other through an intermediary model "CategoryThing". How do I solve this error?

I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

Things Controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :category, :name


  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    @category = Category.all
    @category_things = CategoryThing.all
    @thing.categories.build
  end

  def index
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.all
    @thing = Thing.new
    @things = Thing.all
  end

  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
    if @thing.save
      redirect_to @thing
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def thing_params
      params.require(:thing).permit(:name, :image_path, :avatar, category_ids: [])
    end

end
```

Things/new View:

```
<h1>Add Something!</h1>    
<p>
  <%= form_for @thing, :url => things_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name of the thing" %>
    <br>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :category_names, autocomplete_category_name_things_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :display_picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Routes:

```
Website::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'home_page#home'
  resources :categories
  get "categories/results"
  resources :category_things
  resources :things do
    get :autocomplete_category_name, :on => :collection
    resources :categories
    end 
  get "all/allthings"
    get "all/things/new" => 'things#new'
    resources :comments
  end

end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> 
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js" %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header class=navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div id="homeimage">
      <%= link_to image_tag("Masterpiece.JPG", alt: "Home"), root_path %>
    </div>
    <div id= "searchbar">
      [searchbar]
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= #debug(params) if Rails.env.development?
    %>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141010031643) do

 create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.integer  "thingcount"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "category_things", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "thing_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "things", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I just needed to add `attr_accessor :category_names` to my Thing.rb